# Why is there no "be" in the continuous clause?

Tags: ellipsis, participles

I started reading literature in English and often see sentences where *ing-verb* is without *be*. I met a sentence:

- *Stark's bodyguard spearheading the thing...*

Can you tell me why there **is** no is here? So

- *Stark's bodyguard **is** spearheading the thing...*

I would be happy to help.

I add a full offer: *Well, I'm not sure I'm into the whole elitist vibe they've got going on. The mansion...Stark's bodyguard spearheading the thing...*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "ing" form has other uses:  participles and gerunds.

This is a participle phrase, headed by the participle "spearheading" and functioning to modify the noun "bodyguard".  As with many participle phrases, it can be rewritten as a relative clause

> ...Starks bodyguard that is spearheading the thing.

Answer (score 8):

> Stark's bodyguard spearheading the thing

This is not a sentence, because it doesn't contain a verb. It's a fragment and a noun phrase. It doesn't stand alone here: it's presented as a sort of afterthought, to illustrate the "elitist vibe" the speaker mentioned. This is fairly common in spoken English. It could be more correctly expressed:

> Well, I'm not sure I'm into the whole elitist vibe they've got going on, **such as** *the mansion* and *stark's bodyguard spearheading the thing*.